# Homotopy groups of real Grassmanians

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, grassmannian

Consider real Grassmanians
$$\mathrm{Gr}(n,m)=O(n+m)/O(n)\times O(m),$$
what are the homotopy groups $\pi_k[\mathrm{Gr}(n,m)]$ for generic $k,m,n$?

(I did some search and only found the stable case following Bott periodicity and $k=2$ case discussed in [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207285/second-homotopy-group-of-real-grassmannians-textrmgrn-m-special-case-n). If the generic formula is not available, I would at least like to know the cases of $n=4$, $m=6$ and $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$. Using exact sequence, it seems that I can only determine $\pi_5[\mathrm{Gr}(4,6)]=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ (is that correct?).)

Comment: $Gr(n,m)$ has the homotopy type of a finite CW complex with finite $\pi_1$. The only simply-connected finite CW complexes whose homotopy is completely known are tori. There's a small gap there, but I suspect it's also true that the only connected finite CW complexes with finite $\pi_1$ whose homotopy is completely known are still just the tori. So you will not get a complete answer. There should be a suitable range where the homotopy is known though.

Comment: @tcamps: Tori aren't simply connected. The only finite CW complexes for which all homotopy groups are known are those which are contractible or have contractible universal cover.