# Homotopy groups of real Grassmannians from their long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'd like to understand how to find the homotopy groups of a fibration $F\rightarrow E \rightarrow B$ using a long exact sequence
\begin{equation}
\pi_n(F)\rightarrow 
\pi_n(E)\rightarrow 
\pi_n(B)\rightarrow 
\pi_{n-1}(F)\,.
\end{equation}
For concreteness, I want to focus on the example of first and second homotopy groups of real Grassmannians $\operatorname{Gr}(n,m) = O(n+m)/O(n)\times O(m)$, which were discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207285/second-homotopy-group-of-real-grassmannians-textrmgrn-m-special-case-n). As I understand, the relevant exact sequence is
\begin{equation}
\pi_2[O(n+m)] \rightarrow
\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] \rightarrow
\pi_1[O(n)\times O(m)] \rightarrow
\pi_1[O(n+m)] \rightarrow
\pi_1[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] \rightarrow
\pi_0[O(n)\times O(m)]
\end{equation}
For $N\geq 3$, there's $\pi_2[O(N)] = 0$, $\pi_1[O(N)] = Z_2$,  $\pi_0[O(N)] = Z_2$ [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2455331/homotopy-groups-on-and-son-pi-mon-v-s-pi-mson), so for $n,m\geq 3$ the sequence becomes
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow
\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] \rightarrow
Z_2\times Z_2 \rightarrow
Z_2 \rightarrow
\pi_1[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] \rightarrow
Z_2\times Z_2\,.
\end{equation}
**Question 1:** From the first half of the sequence $0 \rightarrow
\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] \rightarrow
Z_2\times Z_2$ follows that $\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] = Z_2\times Z_2$ (right?), but this is not the correct result, which is $\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)] = Z_2$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207285/second-homotopy-group-of-real-grassmannians-textrmgrn-m-special-case-n). Where's the mistake and how to arrive at the correct result using the sequence?

**Question 2:** Can anything about $\pi_1[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)]$ (which happens to be $Z_2$) be deduced from this sequence?

Comment: The exactness of the sequence $0 \to \pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n, m)] \to \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ only tells you that the map $\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n, m)] \to \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ is injective. In particular, you cannot conclude that it is an isomorphism (as you've noted, it isn't). To determine $\pi_2[\operatorname{Gr}(n,m)]$ you need to understand the next map $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: I'm just a humble physicist, who would like to to learn how to use this tool. If you know of a good resource to learn it, I would be grateful.